# Zoom every object in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to zoom all the tkinter canvas's objects at the same time, but couldn't find a way to do so. I zoom them in a loop instead and the performance is too slow (I have around 5000 objects on the canvas). Is there a way to do it better? Please help.

Comment: Would `Canvas.scale()` solve at least part of your problem?  Note that it only scales coordinates - it doesn't change text sizes, line widths, or some other details that you might want to enlarge when zooming in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that did solve a part of my problem, I would like the text sizes and line widths to be changed during zooming, too. A way to do it is to loop over all text and line objects, do you have any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you aware that the tag "all" will allow you to configure all canvas objects at the same time?

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work with line widths and text sizes:

def zoomer(self, event):
        true_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        true_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.canvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 1.1, 1.1)
        elif event.delta < 0:
            self.canvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 0.9, 0.9)